# PyTorch selecting values from tensor using another tensor describing the locations

Tags: indexing, pytorch, tensor

I have a tensor F = [E, 2, Hm * Wm], a location tensor L = [E, Hp * Wp], and an output tensor O = [E, 2, Hp * Wp]. I want the output tensor at i, j, k to be O[i, j, k] = [i, j, F[i, j, L[i, k]]]. The shape of the output tensor O should be [E, 2, Hp * Wp]. How would I create the output tensor O using pytorch with no for loops?

I've tried using the gather function with pytorch but I'm a starter and am not sure how to go about indexing and the dimension. I know how to solve the problem with for loops, but not without them.